# How to automatically choose default parameters when running "composer install" instead of pressing enter to confirm?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

When I install symfony2 project, i run "composer install" and for each parameter in parameter.yml I have to choose in the console the value. All I need is to let the console choose the default value instead of pressing enter for every parameter.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know `--no-interaction` or `-n` would do the trick.

Comment: Thank you :)   --no-interaction has done the job

Answer (score 4):

--no-interaction is the answer :)